# Amazon sp-api: Listing Items API fails with "Access to requested resource is denied." in Postman

Tags: postman, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am using Amazon SP-API's official models in Postman to get data. I am using `https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token` to get the `access_token`. I use that access token to call different sp-api end-points. **It works fine for most of the end-points and I get correct results for example for "Orders" and "Product Fees"**, however, it doesn't work for the "Listing Items" API. I get the error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
            "details": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I have double checked that the "Product Listings" permission is set in both developer profile as well as the app registration:

App Registration:
[image: App Registration]

Developer Profile:
[image: Developer Profile]

Postman Request:
[image: postman request]

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: after enabling "Product Listing" (or basically adding or removing any roles), one has to re-create the refresh token. That's what I missed.